# Programming Challenge Code taking too much time

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-3.x

I wrote the following code for [this problem.](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1196)

```
prof = sorted([int(input()) for x in range(int(input()))])
student = sorted([int(input()) for x in range(int(input()))])

prof_dates = len(prof)
stud_dates = len(student)

amount = 0

prof_index = 0
stud_index = 0

while stud_index < stud_dates and prof_index < prof_dates:
    if student[stud_index] == prof[prof_index]:
        amount += 1
        stud_index += 1

    elif student[stud_index] > prof[prof_index]:
        prof_index += 1

    elif student[stud_index] < prof[prof_index]:
        stud_index += 1


print(amount)
```

But the code is producing a Time Limit Exceeded Error. Earlier I had tried using a `in` for every item in student but it produced a TLE and I believe that's because the `in` statement is `O(n)`. So, I wrote this code whose steps required are roughly equal to the sum of the lengths of both the lists. But this is also producing a TLE. So, what changes should I make in my code. Is there some particular part which has a high time expense?

Thanks.

Comment: As the code is working, perhaps this is a better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3):

You are using sorting + merging. This takes `O(NlogN + MlogM + N + M)` time complexity.

But you can put professor data in a `set`, check every student year value (from an *unsorted* list)  and get `O(M + N)` complexity (on average).

Note that this approach eliminates the long operation of student list sorting.

Addition: python has built-in sets. For languages that have no such provision, the professor's list is already sorted, so you can just use binary search for every year. The complexity would be `O(NlogM)`.

Comment: A set would be a better choice then a map since only a contains check is necessary.

Comment: But `set` removes duplicate items. And we have to count duplicate items.

Comment: @Some Name  Make set with prof data only, as I wrote. So you'll count all student data, with duplicates. And you should not care about duplicates in prof list, they don't bother.

Comment: @MBo Sorry but check the other answer. There he makes a set out of both of them. This was meant for the other answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw that answer. But in my answer I proposed check every student value against prof set.

Comment: But I'm still getting a TLE with your approach.

Comment: @Dhruv  I proposed the best possible time complexity approach. How much time python program takes to read 1000000 numbers? Is the best method of input used? It is not necessary to read all values in the list.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if we check every student value then checking if an item is in a `set` takes `O(n)` for every date so isn't that slow?

Comment: Each student item (date) check operation is O(1) for set. Overall for N students - O(N)

Answer (score 1):

As the problem basically is to find the intersection of two sets of integers the following code solves the problem in `O(M + N)` when assuming that a dictionary access is possible in `O(1)`

```
prof = set([int(input()) for x in range(int(input()))])
student = set([int(input()) for x in range(int(input()))])

equals_dates = len(prof.intersection(student))
```

Comment: But `set` removes duplicate items. And we have to count duplicate items.